# AWS custom authorizer, identity server and scope

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, identityserver4

I have an identity server in my cloud, so I built a custom authorizer lambda that I would like to re-use for all my API gateway endpoints. 
The problem, this lambda would need to match scope with an incoming token, how would I specify this scope.

I had a few ideas, none of them seems feasible.

1. Somehow match /path and scope, so all requests to /workouts/* have to have workouts scope
2. Have a method tag, that uses scope, not sure how to fetch

Any other less creative ideas?

Comment: what is your auth strategy. In OAuth2, the scope is embedded as part of the bearer. You can also generate multiple authorizers (per scope). and align the correct authorizer to the correct path